# XML Parsing from Non-XML Document

Tags: php, xml, design-patterns, xml-parsing

in a xml/non-xml File there may exist some XML Block that I need to parse and replace with some other string.. The Scenario is something like this..

```
Some Text
<cnt:use name="abc" call="xyz">
   <cnt:param name="x" value="2" />
</cnt:use>
Some Text
```

There is no guarantee that the document is a proper XML document. (there may exist some unclosed Tags. or some other common mistakes that a Stupid people can make while typing HTML). so I can't use SAX or DOM. I can't even pass it to XSLT (am I right ?). So Whats the best way to extract the `<cnt:*>` part from the non-xml Document. and read it then replace with something else.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation why this would be extremely difficult (close to impossible) to do.

Comment: +1 But This is What I have to do.. If nothing else works I've to follow the poor mans way.. `Regular Expression`

Comment: @user256007: There are solutions like [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to convert HTML to XHTML.

Comment: How about telling the users "no, you've asked for sometihng stupid", and then finding out what they actually need, and give that to them. For instance, could they maybe use an actual XML document?

Comment: @John: Oh! What a Solution..... Happy New Year..

@Alejandro: No cause thats not possible either. The document must be exact same. just the `<cnt:*>` part should be replaced with something else

Comment: @user: who makes up requirements like this: "I require you to do something that's difficult or impossible because - well, because I don't know any better and think it should be easy". So, tell them it's not easy like they thought. You'll be doing them a favor.

Comment: @user256007: I'm telling you that if you don't have an XML document, then you must not treat it like XML document: convert to XML, or use a parser that build a DOM from it. What do you mean by "the document must be exact same"? If you allow tag soup, people don't expect surface equality but semantic equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. The Problem is I've to implementing it in PHP :( . Super Sad.. 
So taking ideas from `TagSoup` as mentioned in Mads Hansen's Answer. I've made a Mini SAX Framework on PHP 5.3. https://github.com/neel/SuSAX/blob/master/sax.php.

I am keeping it more like SAX. at the same time I am tracking the tag nesting also. and also keeping a Parse Tree. I've kept a `setNsFocus()` method that Specifies only which tags to follow.

```
<?php
error_reporting(255);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
class MyParser extends \SuSAX\AbstractParser{
    public function open($tag){
        echo ">> open ".$tag->ns().':'.$tag->name().'/'.$this->indentation().($this->parent() ? $this->parent()->name() : '')."\n";
        return "OO";
    }
    public function close($tag){
        echo ">> close ".$tag->ns().':'.$tag->name().'/'.$this->indentation()."\n";
    }
    public function standalone($tag){
        echo ">> standalone ".$tag->ns().':'.$tag->name().'/'.$this->indentation()."\n";
    }
    }
$text = <<<TEXT
Hallo <b>W<html:i>o</html:i>rld</b>
<cnt:tag x="2" y="1">
<cnt:taga x="2" y="1"></cnt:taga>
</cnt:tag>
I am Here
TEXT;
$parser = new \SuSAX\Parser(new MyParser);
$parser->setNsFocus('cnt');
$parser->setText($text);
$text_ = $parser->parse();
var_dump($text_);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I can't even pass it to XSLT (am I
>   right ?).

**Right. XSLT operates on an XML Infoset** that is the representation of a parsed tree (XML document). And this text isn't in general parsable as XML.

**In XSLT 2.0 there is a function `parse-text()`** that can read any text, but the this text must be parsed and until XSLT 3.0 arrives there will not be functions that even vaguely remind such parsing -- and when there are, they would fail, because the text isn't well-formed XML.

**The whole problem of extracting peaces of XML out of a non-well-formed XML is ambiguous and not well-defined**. For example, if an ending tag is missing, how do you decide where exactly to insert it?

Comment: No My assumption is the `<cnt:*>` tags are well formed. However nothing other is guaranteed. So its better to treat as extracting (good) XML Node from Plain text Document which may consist `<` and `>`.

Comment: @user256007: You are contradicting yourself. In the question you say: *there may exist some unclosed Tags*

Answer (score 0):

### [image][TagSoup - Just Keep On Truckin'](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)[image]

You could use [**TagSoup**](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to ensure that all of the documents are well-formed.

> ...a SAX-compliant parser written in Java
>   that, instead of parsing well-formed
>   or valid XML, parses HTML as it is
>   found in the wild: poor, nasty and
>   brutish, though quite often far from
>   short.
>
> TagSoup is designed for people
>   who have to process this stuff using
>   some semblance of a rational
>   application design.
>
> By providing a SAX
>   interface, it allows standard XML
>   tools to be applied to even the worst
>   HTML. TagSoup also includes a
>   command-line processor that reads HTML
>   files and can generate either clean
>   HTML or well-formed XML that is a
>   close approximation to XHTML.

If you are using Saxon, [you can make TagSoup your parser by adding the following option](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/tsaxon/):

> ...you can use the standard Saxon `-x
>   org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser` option,
>   after making sure that TagSoup is on
>   your Java classpath.

Also, [Taggle, a TagSoup in C++, available now](http://www.jezuk.co.uk/arabica/log?id=3591)

Comment: I am not working on Java. However The way I've made it work Is very similer to TagSoup I think.. take a look at my answer.

Comment: Cool. Although, PHP has a Tidy module that may perform most of what you need without having to write any of your own custom code: http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can try to use `DOM::loadHTML` since that method accepts non-well-formed markup.

http://php.net/domdocument.loadhtml